# Handling if statement in when setting view properties

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, view

I'm having a funky bug that's got me stuck for a bit. I simply want to adjust the padding on a SwiftUI view based on the value of a variable (in this case, a variable that determines if we're in dark mode or not). Here's my code:

```
LazyHGrid(rows: rows, spacing:10) {
    // Other stuff here
}.padding(colorScheme == .dark ? [.top, .bottom] : [])
```

My color scheme variable is defined as

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
```

But I keep getting an error on the line with the padding code that says:

"Cannot convert value of type '(ColorScheme) -> some View' to expected argument type 'ColorScheme'"

What do I do?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Note that `View` has a modifier, [`colorScheme(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/colorscheme(_:)), whose type is `(ColorScheme) -> some View`. If you misspelled your `@Environment` variable or it's not actually in the `struct` you think it is, then Swift will only find that modifier, and it will emit the error you're seeing.

Comment: I think this is due to the location of your environment variable. Is the environment variable outside of the scope of the struct that the LazyHGrid exists in? Or is the environment variable in the same struct?